# gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions pull format

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, gcloud, beta, subscriptions

Quick question:
When I pull message from pubsub subscription via command line tool

```
gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions pull MY_SUB
```

I am getting a table with (all details and) data as string (already decoded)
But i want to use it so i did:

```
gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions pull MY_SUB --format=json
```

Than i receive a json with (all details) but the data is encoded.

There is a way to get it parsed with formatting?

Example of publishing message:

```
gcloud beta  pubsub topics publish myTopic "Topic Message" --attribute=Ai=A,Bee=B
```

NO-FORMATTING_RETURN

```
  ─────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────

  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
    ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
    │     DATA    │    MESSAGE_ID   │   ATTRIBUTES   │                                                                             
    ACK_ID                                                                             
    │

  ├─────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────────────

  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
     ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
     │ Topic Message │ 122122177601805 │ Ai=A Bee=B  │ ACK_ID... │

  └─────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────────────

  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
    ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

FORMATTING

```
[
{
"ackId": "ACK_ID..",
"message": {
  "attributes": {
    "Ai": "A",
      "Bee": "B"
    },
     "data": "SGVsbG8gVG9waWM=",
     "messageId": "122121955409996",
     "publishTime": "2017-05-11T10:26:54.143Z"
    }
}
]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are on the right track with the use of [the `--format` argument](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats), but you need to use [projections](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/projections) in order to decode the data. In this case, you need to use the `decode()` projection. Here's how you can perform the same command with the same data except the message's data is base64 decoded.

```
gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions pull MY_SUB --format="json(ackId, message.attributes, message.data.decode(\"base64\").decode(\"utf-8\"), message.messageId, message.publishTime)"

[
  {
    "ackId": "QV5AEkw...D5-NTlF",
    "message": {
      "attributes": {
        "Ai": "A",
        "Bee": "B"
      },
      "data": "Topic Message",
      "messageId": "127236468931635",
      "publishTime": "2017-05-29T23:15:04.637Z"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: For decoded message.data in JSON format, how do you eliminate the backslash-quote \" escaping in the output?

Comment: That sounds like a new question :) There appears to be a `sub()` transform you could use in the `--format` argument after the `json()` projection, or you could always pipe it into something like `sed`.

Comment: Running this command now may result in an error 

`ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`

This can be corrected with an additional the projection decoding

`--format="json(message.attributes, message.data.decode(\"base64\").decode(\"utf-
    8\"), message.messageId, message.publishTime)" `

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my use case:

`gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull test-sub --format="table[no-heading](DATA)" > alert.json`

When I tried the above examples I kept getting errors:

> base64: invalid input
>
> jq: error (at pull.json:10): string ("ewogICJpbm...) is not valid base64 data